# Highlight Duplicate Values in a NetSuite Saved Search

Tags: sql-server, netsuite

I am looking for a way to highlight duplicates in a NetSuite saved search.  The duplicates are in a column called "ACCOUNT" populated with text values.

NetSuite permits adding fields (columns) to the search using a stripped down version of SQL Server.  It also permits conditional highlighting of entire rows using the same code.  However  I don't see an obvious way to compare values between rows of data.

Although duplicates can be grouped together in a summary report and identified by a count of 2 or more, I want to show duplicate lines separately and highlight each.

The closest thing I found was a clever formula that calculates a running total [here](http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/05/26/solving-the-netsuite-cumulative-saved-search-tally-challenge/):

```
sum/* comment */({amount})
 OVER(PARTITION BY {name}
 ORDER BY {internalid}
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

I wonder if it's possible to sort results by the field being checked for duplicates and adapt this code to identify changes in the "ACCOUNT" field between a row and the previous row.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: if you do not necessarily need to show duplicates in different rows, just group the results by ACCOUNT column, get the result counts for each group in an additional column, and highlight if that count value is > 1.

Comment: @tt_emrah, yes I thought of that and mentioned it in my question.  I'm more interested in a method to look for duplicates on separate rows, that can be used in a variety of situations.  There must be a way to compare a current row value to a prior row value and check for a match.  Then I could sort by that field so that any matches would be on contiguous rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This post has been edited. I have left the progression as a learning experience about NetSuite.**

**Original - plain SQL way - not suitable for NetSuite**

Does something like this meet your needs? The test data assumes looking for duplicates on id1 and id2. **Note: This does not work in NetSuite as it supports limited SQL functions. See comments for links.**

```
declare @table table (id1 int, id2 int, value int);

insert @table values
(1,1,11),
(1,2,12),
(1,3,13),
(2,1,21),
(2,2,22),
(2,3,23),
(1,3,1313);
--select * from @table order by id1, id2;

select  t.*,
        case when dups.id1 is not null then 1 else 0 end is_dup     --identify dups when there is a matching dup record
from    @table t
left    join (  --subquery to find duplicates
        select  id1, id2
        from    @table
        group   by id1, id2
        having count(1) > 1
        ) dups
        on  dups.id1 = t.id1
        and dups.id2 = t.id2
order   by t.id1, t.id2;
```

**First Edit - NetSuite target but in SQL.**

This was a SQL test based on the example available syntax provided in the question since I do not have NetSuite to test against. This will give you a value greater than 1 on each duplicate row using a similar syntax. **Note: This will give the appropriate answer but not in NetSuite.**

```
select  t.*,
        sum(1) over (partition by id1, id2)
from    @table t
order   by t.id1, t.id2;
```

**Second Edit - Working NetSuite version**

After some back and forth here is a version that works in NetSuite:

```
sum/* comment */(1) OVER(PARTITION BY {name})
```

This will also give a value greater than 1 on any row that is a duplicate.

**Explanation**

This works by summing the value 1 on each row included in the partition. The partition column(s) should be what you consider a duplicate. If only one column makes a duplicate (e.g. user ID) then use as above. If multiple columns make a duplicate (e.g. first name, last name, city) then use a comma-separated list in the partition. SQL will basically group the rows by the partition and add up the 1s in the `sum/* comment */(1)`. The example provided in the question sums an actual column. By summing 1 instead we will get the value 1 when there is only 1 ID in the partition. Anything higher is a duplicate. I guess you could call this field duplicate count.

Comment: Sorry. I did not really understand the limitations of NetSuite and I don't have it available for testing. However I have provided an Option 2 that follows the suggested syntax available...I can't test if it can be adapted to NetSuite...

Comment: Saved search functionality is much different than standard SQL queries.  The link above called Saved Searches Explained provides the basics.

Comment: Can Option 2 be used? It is structurally similar to the example you provided. `sum(1) over (partition by id1, id2)`

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work. Saved searches don't support `SELECT` or the way you reference table fields. Saved searches use a form of SQL Server to resolve to values but the syntax is different. They are created on a single record type such as employees, transactions, audit logs, or files.  By default results include every record of that type. Users filter records by selecting fields from the saved search UI sometimes including a formula for part or all of the criteria. Users then choose which fields to display in the output.  Columns in the results can be defined by formula.

Comment: Option 2 needs tweaking to work in NetSuite - your original "clever formula" was `sum/* comment */({amount})
 OVER(PARTITION BY {name}
 ORDER BY {internalid}
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` so my suggestion would be `sum/* comment */(1)
 OVER(PARTITION BY {name})` and if the result is greater than 1 then it is a duplicate.

Comment: That works!  If you would edit your answer to reflect this I'll accept and award the bounty.  Can you also explain how it works?

Comment: I have made the updates. Let me know if something is not clear.