# How to prevent duplicate items on Sales Order within Netsuite

Tags: transactions, duplicates, netsuite, items

We have had duplicate items show up on our Sales Orders from time to time.  I am wanting to either set up a saved search or workflow to audit and catch these.
I found someone mentioned a script to go through each line and consolidate, but that is a bit beyond my level of expertise.

I tried setting up a Transaction Search, but I could not get it to look at only Sales Orders where there are duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I was able to get a Saved Search to give a list of Items (SKUs) that have duplicate Orders.
I grouped by Project(JOB) and used the Code below, that would Identify if there was a duplicate (if greater than 0)

```
CASE WHEN (sum/* comment */(1) OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT({custbody_bb_project.entityid},CONCAT('.',{item.name})))) > 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
```

This was based on this answer:  [Highlight Duplicate Values in a NetSuite Saved Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131733/highlight-duplicate-values-in-a-netsuite-saved-search)